# How to tell where the stored procedure creates duplicates

Tags: sql

The sp is used to add an additional unit to an existing customer. There are three tables used. Information is entered into the first table, then partially info from the first table is entered into a second table, and last table has all info from the first table once again. The problem is that every time I add a new unit the unit before (UB) ends up to be duplicated 8 times. If I add another unit another 8 rows are added to that unit (UB). Moreover, when duplicates are created new id's are assigned which are the PKs. Any suggestions on how to fix this problem.

Thank you.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddAdditionalUnit]
(   
    @FPN varchar(20), 
    @UN varchar(20),
    @EFFD datetime, 
    @EXPD datetime,             
    @ENDERSNR int,
    @PRM decimal(19,2),
    @CID int,
    @COVPTID int,   
    @ADDID varchar(7),  
    @MODID varchar(7),
    @CustID int
)

AS
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO POLICYS
(
    Facility_Policy_Number, 
    Unit_Number, 
    Effective_Date, 
    Expiration_Date, 
    Endorsement_Date,
    Endorsement_Nbr,
    Premium,
    Coverage_ID,
    Coverage_Percent_Theft_ID,
    Add_ID,
    Add_Date,
    Mod_ID,
    Mod_Date

)
VALUES
(   
    @FPN, 
    @UN,
    @EFFD,
    @EXPD,  
    GETDATE(),
    @ENDERSNR,
    @PRM,
    @CID,
    @COVPTID,
    @ADDID,
    GETDATE(),
    @MODID,
    GETDATE()
)
INSERT INTO Policy_Facility_Customer
(
    Cert_Number, 
    Facility_ID, 
    Customer_ID, 
    Add_ID, 
    Add_Date, 
    Mod_ID, 
    Mod_Date
)

SELECT     
    POLICYS.Cert_Number, 
    FACILITYS.ID AS FacilityID, 
    @CustID as Customer_ID, 
    POLICYS.Add_ID, 
    POLICYS.Add_Date, 
    POLICYS.Mod_ID, 
    POLICYS.Mod_Date

FROM         FACILITYS INNER JOIN
                      POLICYS ON FACILITYS.Facility_Policy_Number = POLICYS.Facility_Policy_Number

WHERE     (FACILITYS.Facility_Policy_Number = @FPN)

declare @PTCID int
SET @PTCID = 1;


INSERT INTO POLICYS_Transactions
(      
      Cert_Number,
      Facility_Policy_Number,
      Unit_Number,
      Effective_Date,
      Expiration_Date,
      Endorsement_Date,
      Endorsement_Nbr,
      Premium,
      Coverage_ID,
      Coverage_Percent_Theft_ID,
      Policy_Tran_Code_ID,
      Add_ID,
      Add_Date,
      Mod_ID,
      Mod_Date 
)

SELECT

  POLICYS.Cert_Number, 
    POLICYS.Facility_Policy_Number, 
    POLICYS.Unit_Number,
    POLICYS.Effective_Date,
    POLICYS.Expiration_Date,
    POLICYS.Endorsement_Date,
    POLICYS.Endorsement_Nbr,
    POLICYS.Premium,
    POLICYS.Coverage_ID,
    POLICYS.Coverage_Percent_Theft_ID,
    @PTCID, 
    POLICYS.Add_ID, 
    POLICYS.Add_Date, 
    POLICYS.Mod_ID, 
    POLICYS.Mod_Date

FROM         FACILITYS INNER JOIN
                      POLICYS ON FACILITYS.Facility_Policy_Number = POLICYS.Facility_Policy_Number

WHERE     (FACILITYS.Facility_Policy_Number = @FPN)

END
```

Comment: Did you check your select queries to see which one is bringing duplicates?

Comment: can you provide schemas of your tables? from the looks of it, facility_policy_number is not a primary key, so if you're joining on it, every joined row would create multiple inserts into the Policy_Facility_Customer

Comment: Kritner you are right. I am not joining on primary keys. Who set up the tables there are not a foreign keys into the tables. The middle table contains the Primary keys of other tables just as columns not as foreign keys and I need to use that one to connect the tables together but the PK of the table is no where in the other tables as a foreign key. Does it make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK here is what is happening, you want to insert one record and then one record into the second table based on what you inserted into the first table but you are not specifying in the where clause what record except through something that is not a Primary key and thus not unique.

You should return the PK of the record inserted in the first table using an output clause (SQL Server specific, there may be a differnt method for a differnt database backend) to a table variable.

Then you should join the first table to that table vairaible so that you only get the one record you want. Further, it is a best practice to never insert to a table without using a where not exists clause to ensure you are not duplicating exisiting data.

Comment: Thank you! I used more variables for the where clause and it doesn't duplicate :) I will start looking into the does not exists clause. Thank you!